# The idea of Boyer-Moore's good suffix search

Tags: string, algorithm, search

One of the key features of Boyer-Moore's algorithm is searching for good suffix. It requires to build a table of shifts on each possible suffix? But how to build this shift table? I don't understand it. Thank you!

Comment: There are plenty of expositions of the algorithm out there. I don't think that simply saying "I don't understand" makes for a very good question.

Comment: But I couldn't find simple explanation.

Comment: Depending on how simple you want the explanation to be, there may not be a simple general explanation of the whole algorithm.  If your goal is to understand the algorithm, then letting us know where you get stuck will help us provide you with explanations that may let you get past that particular conceptual hurdle.

Comment: I just get stuck on how to generate a shift table for a good suffix heuristic. I understand how this alogrithm works except this moment.

Comment: There are two tables involved for the good suffix rule.  One table is used first (called `L` on wikipedia). The other table is used when L isn't useful, and is called `H`.  Are you having trouble with both tables?  Are you having trouble understanding what these tables should contain, or are you having trouble with the process of filling them with the proper values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an excellent explanation in [the german wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer-Moore-Algorithmus). I know this might not help, but with a bit of luck you can try to understand the example which is very clear.